# Interpreting features created by xgb.create.features() function in xgboost in R

Tags: r, xgboost

How can I interpret the features created by the `xgb.create.features()` in the xgboost package in R?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(xgboost)

data(mtcars)
X = as.matrix(mtcars[, -9])
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = X, label = Y)

model = xgb.train(data = dtrain, 
                  eval = "auc",
                  verbose =0,  maximize = TRUE, 
                  params = list(objective = "binary:logistic",
                                eta = 0.1,
                                max_depth = 6,
                                subsample = 0.8,
                                lambda = 0.1 ), 
                  nrounds = 10)

dtrain1 = xgb.create.features(model, X)
colnames(dtrain1)

'mpg' 'cyl' 'disp' 'hp' 'drat' 'wt' 'qsec' 'vs' 'gear' 'carb' 'V13' 'V14' 'V15' 'V16' 'V23' 'V24' 'V33' 'V34' 'V43' 'V44' 'V53' 'V54' 'V63' 'V64' 'V73' 'V74' 'V83' 'V84' 'V93' 'V94' 'V103' 'V104'

new_data = as.matrix(dtrain1)
new_data = data.frame(new_data)
head(new_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fitted 10 trees. These 10 trees have as many leaves as there are columns V13 - V104. These leaves are your new variables.

Lets assume the first tree had 4 leaves and that Observation Mazda RX4 fell into the 2nd leaf, it would be encoded 0, 1, 0, 0. The variables corresponding to this would be V13, V14, V15, V16. The same for the second tree and so forth.

You can conclude based on the variable names which columns correspond to which trees:
'V13' 'V14' 'V15' 'V16' - first tree
'V23' 'V24' - second tree
'V103' 'V104' - 10th tree

As explained in the help for the function:

> We found that boosted decision trees are a powerful and very
> convenient way to implement non-linear and tuple transformations of
> the kind we just described. We treat each individual tree as a
> categorical feature that takes as value the index of the leaf an
> instance ends up falling in. We use  1-of-K coding of this type of
> features.
>
> For example, consider the boosted tree model in Figure 1
> with 2 subtrees,  where the first subtree has 3 leafs and the second 2
> leafs. If an instance ends up in leaf 2 in the first subtree and leaf
> 1 in second subtree, the overall input to the linear classifier will
> be the binary vector \code{[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]}, where the first 3 entries
> correspond to the leaves of the first subtree and last 2 to those of
> the second subtree.

Do note that this variable set warrants another hyper parameter tune and is prone to over-fitting. Check out feature importance for the model before and after `xgb.create.features`.

Comment: when you said "*check out feature importance*", does it mean that if a new variable appears at the top of the new feature importance (after `xgb.create.features`), it could be a warning about overfitting ?

Comment: @demarsylvain not necessarily. You can check for over-fitting  by conducting [nested re-sampling](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html).

Comment: I though there was someting new to check, I'm already using cross-validation. Thank you. Another question: if I increase the number of iterations of the model, let's say 1000, `xgb.create.features` will create a lot of features. Is there tip to reduce this, or the best way is to create all of them ?

Comment: I don't think that many trees will be beneficial, but you will need to try it. BTW using `xgb.create.features` on all the train data and then evaluating the model in the 2nd step by cross validation is going to lead you to wrong conclusions (data leakage).

Comment: In order to evaluate the usefulness of `xgb.create.features` you will need to perform it in each fold of CV.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to replace the derived names with some sort of concatenation of the original feature names? Alternatively, or perhaps better, to produce a some sort of reference table for each derived feature?